# Exporting ldd raster from grass to PCRaster fails

Tags: grass-gis, flow-direction, pcraster

I successfully exported Float32 SCALAR data with

```
r.out.gdal input=$file output=$file.map format=PCRaster type=Float32 createopt="PCRASTER_VALUESCALE=VS_SCALAR"
```

but for ldd data (previously resampled to PCRaster notation of directions map) it fails on command:

```
r.out.gdal input=drainage output=ldd.map format=PCRaster type=Int32 createopt="PCRASTER_VALUESCALE=VS_LDD"
```

What GDT cell type I should use? Error is:

```
ERROR 4: PCRaster driver: Unable to create raster
```

UPD: If I don't use type parameter at all, program writes file, but then grass crashes and the resulting file has only zeros inside.

Version of Grass is 7.8.7

UPD: all data exported is in raster format. I am exporting directions raster created with r.watershed utility.

UPD2: [image: no layers]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example with the North Carolina sample dataset? https://grass.osgeo.org/download/data/#NorthCarolinaDataset --> full dataset.

Comment: I could, but I dont see there any raster, and vectors are of "old topology format". How can I reproduce this in that dataset?

Comment: I can of course download raster data independently, from here https://grassbook.org/datasets/datasets-3rd-edition/ but I don't think I would hit the goal.

Comment: Please explain (in the question) how vector topology is involved here as the question seems to be about raster data?

Comment: Yes, I simply explored this dataset, and I've found there only vector layers, these also in old topology format. For my task, if you want me to reproduce this error, I need DEM raster or directions raster.

Comment: Not sure what you mean: the North Carolina sample dataset --> "full dataset" contains both raster and vector maps. See also the list at https://www.grassbook.org/wp-content/uploads/grasslocations/nc_spm_08_contents.html . One of the several included raster DEM map is called "elevation".

Comment: Yes, I see. But that's what I see in my GUI whien I open this full dataset (image attached to question)

Comment: Something must have gone wrong when opening the dataset. BTW: any change to update to GRASS GIS 8? Meanwhile v7 is no longer receiving updates.

Comment: Should I use grass 8 for now? If so, I should use another docker image from grass. Maybe you could give a link to a proper image with a new grass version, that would work? Because I use mundialis/grass-py3-pdal:7.8.7-debian

Comment: I'll tell you, we are today/tomorrow restructuring the docker images which have been moved from mundialis to OSGeo, at https://hub.docker.com/r/osgeo/grass-gis/tags (better tags upcoming this week).

Comment: Discussion (as it is complex) is still ongoing, see https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/pull/3075 and https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-website/pull/371

Comment: Done. The docker images are still building. The web page is now finally updated reflecting the new organization: https://grass.osgeo.org/download/docker/